# How can I call Angular's $httpBackend directly?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What is the simplest way to call `$httpBackend` manually?

Yes, I am aware that you are supposed to use `$http` instead, however this is a special use case: I am augmenting the `$exceptionHandler` and want to send a log message back to the server, however I can't use `$http` since it will trigger an `$apply` which could retrigger an exception causing an infinite loop and locking up the browser.

Most examples (and my own code) has used jQuery to issue the Ajax call to log the error. I'm trying to solve it with out using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

**Warning this is an undocumented API** on purpose and I'm certain the Angular team reserves the right to change the signature.

That being said here is the minimal backend call I've been able to create:

```
$httpBackend('POST', '/some/url',          //method and url
    JSON.stringify(buildLogInfo()),        //request body
    function(status,resp,headerString){    //response call back
        console.log('manual backend call',status,resp,headerString);
    },
    {"Content-Type": "application/json"}   //request headers
);
```